# Determine what javascript function is called in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, plugins

I am actually working on an ongoing project that is half way completed.
I have to:

- Find `javascript` functions that are trigger when some `checkboxes` are selected,
- inspect the `CSS` of some elements

I would like to know a trick or a plugin to determine them, this way I can speed my development process.

Comment: How about the browser developer tools?

Comment: The browser developer tools doesn't provide me with the tools to verify the javascript associate and the listeners.

Comment: can you elaborate and show me how I can analyze the functions javascript that are executed.

Comment: You can use [`getEventListeners()`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#geteventlistenersobject) to find event listeners for a DOM element, and [`monitorEvents()`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#monitoreventsobject-events) to watch for events as they occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the developer tool of google chrome.

You might to look on how to debug put break points in your script.

you have an how to use [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Answer (score 0):

The Developer tools of Chrome seems to be an eligible choice.